# Can a user set their own password using powershell after it has expired assuming one account can be logged onto to run the script

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords, credentials

I'm curious to know if a user can reset their own password via AD after it has expired using a powershell script. I'm assuming it's not possible but would love it if someone could prove me wrong:

We have 10 domains, and I have an account in each domain each using the same password, I would like to know if it's possible if I could (using powershell) write a script to connect to each domain and set the password (even after the password has expired).

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Create account 2) Set expiration date 3) test 4) profit!

Comment: @PeeHaa that's not what I asked for.

Comment: Well right now your question can be answered with "Yes" or "No". Which (imo) is an indicator of a bad question. It is also expected that you try some stuff on your own and only ask if you get stuck solving your problem.

Comment: @Marc a yes or no answer is fine. However all help would be appreciated was also tacked onto the end. I'm not here for smart-a** replies I'm here to find an answer to a question based on information i don't know. I don't expect people to do the work for me, I expect a yes or no, and any further that they can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be possible as far as I know, as it would open a security risk to allow users to reset their own expired passwords.

However, if you are a sys-admin you will have different privileges.

So if you want to change your passwords on all 10 domains, write a script to change them before your password expires (and a script to alert you when you password is about to expire on the different domains).

Comment: Thanks for that info, I didn't think it would be possible for that very reason, but thought perhaps there may be some built in exception. We start getting alerts via popup balloons 14 days before the expiry date so that should prompt me and yes I guess I'll just have to do it before the expiry. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!